# QuickBlox Room Occupant

Tags: android, quickblox

The code below retrieves room occupant ID for Group Chat.

I need the room occupant Login not the ID anyone with an idea?

```
  String sender = QBChatUtils.parseRoomOccupant(message.getFrom());
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to get login of QBUser. QuickBlox Chat Module can return you only id, so in this case you need to get QBUser from Users Module by this id and the user has login you need.

```
String sender = QBChatUtils.parseRoomOccupant(message.getFrom());

QBUsers.getUser(Integer.parseInt(sender), new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;
            qbUserResult.getUser().getId();
        }
    } 
});
```

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Retrieve_User_by_ID